# JaxB, Eclipse Moxy, polymorhpic mapping

Tags: jaxb, moxy

I have a `Parent` and a `Child` class.

A `House` class has a field of type `Parent` which can refer to a `Child` object. I need to map it to XML using Eclipse Moxy.

Its xsd would be something like:

`<xs:complexType name="Parent" abstract="true">
...other fields...`

`<xs:complexType name="Child" >
    <xs:extension base="Parent">
...other fields...`

`<xs:element name="child" type="Child" substitutionGroup="parent" />
 <xs:element name="parent" type="Parent" abstract="true" />`

`<xs:complexType name="House">
    <xs:element ref="parent"/>`

House class contains a JAXBElement to point to Parent:
`@XmlElementRef(name = "parent", namespace = "abc", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<? extends Parent> parent;`

How do I map `House` class through House.oxm.xml file so this polymorphic mapping works correctly?

`<java-type name="House" xml-accessor-type="NONE">
            <java-attributes>
               <xml-element-ref java-attribute="?????????"/>`

I tried using '@'  in the mapping but it doesn't work - it just adds the reference String (@Parent) of the object to XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole issue was because of:

`@XmlElementRef(name = "parent", namespace = "abc", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<? extends Parent> parent;`

After many futile attempts to fix it, I came across this defect: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=327811

After referring to its code, I saw that it addressed a situation very similar to mine, but used just @XmlElementRef annotation on the supertype, without using anything else like JAXBElement or supplying any other parameters to @XmlElementRef.

I tried that (and removed its mapping from oxm file) and it worked like a charm! I hope this answer helps anybody else who is stuck with the same problem.